# Python - count number of times a number greater than or equal to 2 appears in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
difference_1 = pd.DataFrame(difference)
print(difference_1)
```

How do I count he number of times a number greater than or equal to 2 occurs?

Comment: Please read the guidelines on how to write a question. Especially important would be to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [0,1,2,3,4], 'c': [-1,2,3,0,2]})
>>> df >= 2
   a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1   True  False   True
2   True   True   True
3   True   True  False
4   True   True   True
>>> (df >= 2).values.sum()
10
```

Comment: You suppose it 's a dict?

Comment: @Teshtek No, that's just one way to create an arbitrary dataframe to serve as an example. `df` here *is* a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop to go through all the values and keeping a counter when the value is greater or equal to two. You're code will look like:

```
difference_1 = pd.DataFrame(difference)
counter = 0
for number in difference_1:
    if number >= 2: 
        counter += 1
```

Comment: It would help for efficiency if you made use of vectorized functions built into Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a simple vector of elements right ?

If is it you can just do this :

```
print(len([x for x in df if x >= 2]))
```